# How can I evaluate my club options?

Tags: world-golf-tour

Are there clubs worth getting, and does it make a difference?

What is the best club to credits cost ratio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried enough clubs to weigh in on the club-to-credits ratio, but you can rent clubs at a low price, typically 15% of the cost of buying them.  If you don't want to spend cash on rentals, you can earn credits by [taking surveys or watching videos](http://www.wgt.com/user/offers.aspx).

You can also follow World Golf Tour on Facebook or Twitter, and keep an eye out for announcements about free stuff.  [Rentals were free after Thanksgiving last year, and again for a couple of days in January](http://www.wgt.com/news/archive/2011/11/22/free-golf-club-rentals-this-holiday-weekend.aspx).